# How to add additional commands to start clause in the package.json?

Tags: reactjs

I have my package.json start like this

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
```

How to add also “json-server db.json” to start ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all) module to be able to run multiple tasks.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "run-s rscript jserver",
    "rscript": "react-scripts start",
    "jserver": "json-server db.json"
}
```

Comment: does not work both localhost:3000 and localhost:3000/myjosn load the application not the json data

Comment: It was asked about how to run two commands in one npm run: that's what was answered. You've used my answer to write yours with extra details--please accept my answer as the rightful answer.

Answer (score 0):

This combination worked with me. I had to choose another port + run as parallel.

```
"start": "run-p jserver rscript",
    "rscript": "react-scripts start",
    "jserver": "json-server db.json --port 3004",
```

Answer (score 0):

One more solution to use Concurrently (https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently)

```
npm install concurrently --save

"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"react-scripts start\"",
    "server": "nodemon server/app",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this,

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start && json-server --watch db.json",
}
```

**Note:** You must install your `json-server` globally like `npm install -g json-server`.
Also make sure your `db.json` file don't have any error / typo, because when `json-server` it compiling the `db.json` file and if any type mistake in `db.json` file it show the error like

```
Error Showing: ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
Error Showing: ERR! errno 1
```